# No picture on new RPi Official display

Tags: display, touchscreen

Just received my new Raspberry Pi official touch display today.  Very nice hardware, can't wait to use it.  However, I have hooked it up according to the instructions on both MCM and RaspberryPi.org and yet I get no display output.  The only quirk when I wired the first time was that I had the display connector ribbon upside down, but since no contact it should not have had an impact.  Any thoughts?  The Pi appears to power as a Pi usually would, but then since I can't find an LED indicator on the LCD controller board, I don't know whether or not the display is even powering. 
I have tried powering the entire setup via both USB power in ports, first the display controller and then as MCM does in the video via the Pi power in.  Very surprised to not have any pictures still.  Any guidance would be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: What does "since no contact" mean. Can we see photos of the connections?

Comment: Is the green light flashing on the raspberry pi? How many times does it flash?

Comment: Have you tried booting with both the display and an external (HDMI) display? If the touch display is not at all recognized or powered, the external display should turn on.  Also, check these troubleshooting steps [from [the MCM website on this display](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/83-16872)]: 
`Troubleshooting:
 1.  Power should go into the adapter board FIRST, then to the Pi.
 2.  Ensure your power supply is rated for 5V@2A.
 3.  Double check all connections - GPIO, USB, and ribbon cables.
 4.  If powering via GPIO, make sure USB is not connected.
...`

Comment: `...
 5.  If powering via USB, make sure GPIO is not connected.
 6.  Update your OS to the latest version using sudo apt-get update upgrade.
 7.  Try swapping USB cables (higher quality is preferred.)
 8.  Does your Pi boot without being connected to the touchscreen? If not, reflash your SD card and try again.
`

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause after some trial Friday.  It turned out that my plan to use a keyboard and mouse with the new screen; and update the software while connected to the display, was the wrong plan.  After plugging the Pi in via HDMI I ran the updates and the screen booted up no issue after that.  Sorry for the thread.